# Images not found after changing folder

Tags: html, css

I am just starting to look into html and css. I have already build something that should become a website, however when I wanted to organize the files I have put picture and code in two seperate folders and now the preview won't show the images. The rest of the CSS file still applies ...

Can anyone help with this newbie problem?

Thanks ! :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: It's a path issue....

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the paths in the CSS file too; if they used to be e.g.

- style.css
- apple.jpg

and you had

```
background-image: url(apple.jpg);
```

and now you move them to

- css/style.css
- images/apple.jpg

you'd need a relative path like

```
background-image: url(../images/apple.jpg);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It somehow still doesn't work. I must be doing something wrong …

Comment: Look in your browser developer console to see if it's trying to make requests that end up 404-ing :)